# CSS first-child selector not working properly

Tags: css, css-selectors

Here is my HTML:

```html
<header id="banner" class="body">
    <h1><a href="#">New UGS Project! <br><strong>This is the sub-title</strong></a></h1>

    <nav><ul>
        <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
    </ul></nav>

</header><!-- /#banner -->
```

And my CSS:

```
#banner nav a:first-child:hover{
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 8px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 8px; 
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
}
```

I would like to select ONLY the first link, "home", to apply the border radius.  I am struggling with this CSS3 selector...

Comment: `:first-child` is not a CSS3 selector.

Comment: a is the first child for all lis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a` has no `first-child`. `li` does.

```
#banner nav ul > li a:first-child:hover{
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 8px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 8px; 
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
}
```

Comment: But each `a` *is* the first child. `li:first-child` doesn't mean the first child of `li` either; you're applying border radius to the `li` here, which isn't quite correct.

Answer (score 6):

Each `a` is wrapped into an `li` element, so `a` is always the the first (and last) child of its parent `li`. You have to select the first `li` of its parent `ul` element. Some example selectors:

```
#banner nav li:first-child a:hover {
#banner nav li:first-child:hover a {
#banner nav li:first-child:hover {
```

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is this:

```
#banner nav li:first-child a:hover {
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 8px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 8px; 
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
}
```